# Silent push notification with Firebase in iOS10

Tags: ios, firebase, ios10, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can't call method in background using silent push notifications.

1. Checked "Background Modes" > "Background fetch" and "Remote notification".
2. Add method to send data to Firebase.

`func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.viewController.sendData()
    }`

3. Send push notification with `content_available: true`.

When app is in foreground, `sendData()` is called. But when in background, it isn't called.

Comment: Did you implement applicationReceivedRemoteMessage? It's more of a foreground thing but it needs to be implemented either way. Oh, and what is the implementation of sendData()?

Comment: I resolve this problem with using Firebase cloud messaging!

Comment: can you copy-paste a FCM data template for silent notification?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set time_to_live = 0. It works for me.